# Copy text to clipboard on page ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy

I'm trying to offer the user a way to copy automatically a text when he/she enters the page. 
I could make it work using an input and a button like this:

```
<input type="text" id="text-field" value="Some text">
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()"> Copy </button>
```

and this js function:

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  $('#text-field').select();
  try {
    if (!document.execCommand('copy')) {
      throw false;
    }
    alert('Copied');
  } catch (error) {
    alert('An error has occurred!');
  }
};
```

When I click the button the text is copied.

The problem is I want to do this on page load. So, I tried writing something like this:

```
$(function() {
  copyToClipboard();
});
```

But it displays 'An has occurred!'

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet that reproduces the problem here? And/or could you print the error to get what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried using the Jquery `.load()` and `.ready()` methods?

Comment: trigger you button click  on **window.addEventListener("load", function(){});**

Comment: It doesn't wok with triggering button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior.

https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#integration-with-rich-text-editing

> Copy and cut commands triggered through a scripting API will only
>   affect the contents of the real clipboard **if the event is dispatched**
>   **from an event that is trusted and triggered by the user**, or if the
>   implementation is configured to allow this.

Comment: I've seen web applications that make this work. How do they do it?

Comment: @nigal On page load? Do you have any example? There may be some hackish ways but I doubt it, especially on recent browsers.

Comment: I mean I highly doubt anyone would like his clipboard to be written into just by visiting a page.

Comment: [Loom](http://useloom.com) copies a sharing url after you record a video

Comment: @nigal I assume "after you record a video" means after an action triggered by the user (as opposed to page load).

Comment: Loom is a chrome extension that allow you to record your screen. When you stop the recording a new tab is opened and a sharing url is copied. Maybe the url is copied by the chrome extension instead of the new page opened. I'm not sure about this

Comment: @nigal "When you stop the recording": isn't this a user action? Then the URL could be copied at that moment (not by the new URL). Then again maybe extensions have different permissions, as you mentioned.

Comment: I tried copying the text from the extension and it worked!